# Errors in up & down functions - solidity code

Tags: events, emit

In below code got errors for up n down function, please check and advise.

Regards
Syed

pragma solidity ^0.7.6;

contract TugOfWar {

```
int public score = 0;
int constant endAt = 1 ether;
bool public gameOver = false;

event ScoreChanged(uint amount, bool up);
event GameEnded(bool up); // where 'up' indicates which side won.

function up() external payable {
    
    require(msg.value > 0);
    require(!gameOver);

    int value = int(msg.value);
    score += value;
```

checkIfGameOver();

```
    emit ScoreChanged(msg.value, true); // where the second argument indicates the direction
}

function down() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    require(!gameOver);

    int value = int(msg.value);
    score -= value;
```

checkIfGameOver();

```
    emit ScoreChanged(msg.value, true);
}

function checkIfGameOver() internal {
    if(score >= endAt || score <= endAt * -1) {
        gameOver = true;

        //
        emit GameEnded(true); // where the argument indicates which side has won. 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The up and down functions worked when I tested them in REMIX IDE.

You can add messages to require statements. Then you can see where the transaction went wrong. e.g.

```
require(msg.value > 0, "No Value Sent");
```

If you did hit this error, then you have not sent any value. In REMIX you would add it in the VALUE field before you click on the button corresponding to the payable function "up" or "down".

[image]

you can also add an error message to the gameOver require statement:

```
require(!gameOver, "Game Already Over");
```

you'd probably also want to indicate in which direction the score changed.
So when the "up" function is called you would emit:

```
emit ScoreChanged(msg.value, true); // where the second argument indicates the direction
```

but when the "down" function is called emit:

```
emit ScoreChanged(msg.value, false); // where the second argument indicates the direction
```

same on the game over event:

```
emit GameEnded(score >= 0); // where the argument indicates which side has won.
```

finally, i'd suggest you emit the event "ScoreChanged" BEFORE you check "checkIfGameOver". So that the order of the events is correct.